# Integer values in compile time

Tags: c++, enums, compile-time

I have to write some constants in different files with some integer id. For example:

```
#define MESSAGE_FIRST 0
```

In other file:

```
#define MESSAGE_ANOTHER 1
```

Any ways to get that id automatically in compile time? Something like:

```
#define MESSAGE_AUTO GetNextId()
```

I can't use enums here because this directives will be in different files.

Thanks.

p.s. GCC, Linux

Comment: The standard does not have something like \_\_COUNTER\_\_ (similar to \_\_LINE\_\_) AFAIK. p.s. In my own preprocessor I have this.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do that outside of external code generation.  But maybe if you give a more thorough description of the actual problem you are trying to solve, we can give you a better solution.

Comment: Do they have to be in different files? Or can they all include a single header file with these values in?

Comment: the need for such a file-crossing compile-time counter smells like a design flaw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a compile-time counter, with inheritance and function overloading:

```
template<unsigned int n> struct Count { bool data[n]; };
template<int n> struct Counter : public Counter<n-1> {};
template<> struct Counter<0> {};
Count<1> GetCount(Counter<1>);

#define MAX_COUNTER_NUM 64
#define COUNTER_VALUE (sizeof(GetCount(Counter<MAX_COUNTER_NUM + 1>())) / sizeof(bool))
#define INC_COUNTER Count<COUNTER_VALUE + 1> GetCount(Counter<COUNTER_VALUE + 1>);
```

You can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/0t0Np). Also works with msvc.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using GCC. GCC has the (AFAIK per-file) macro called `__COUNTER__` that increments by one after every use.

Note that this is an extension and not included in standard C++.

Another option is using an enum:

```
enum {
    FIRST = 0,
    SECOND,
    THIRD
};
```

Or you can do this manually using preprocessor directives like this:

```
#define FIRST 0
#define SECOND (1 + FIRST)
#define THIRD (1 + SECOND)
```

Comment: What about latest tip: This is useful when everything is one file, I need in different and a few programmers will edit this code so possible conflicts.

Comment: Please use parens when defining SECOND and THIRD.